# Castle nVelocity and whitspace gobbling

Tags: .net, nvelocity

I am using Castle nVelocity to create templates to produce some text files.  I have found that if I do something like the following in my template, that my output line is indented in the resulting file as it is in the template.

```
#foreach( $row in $report.Rows )
    Output this row: ${row}
#end
```

To get the output I want I have to write my template like this:

```
#foreach( $row in $report.Rows )
Output this row: ${row}
#end
```

Is there a way to tell nVelocity to gobble the white space so that the line will not be indented in the output but so that I can leave it indented in the template for readability?

Comment: Consider posting to the Castle mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/castle-project-users

Comment: That link appears to be dead.

Comment: works for me. Otherwise look up castle-project-users on Google Groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot do this with out of the box functionality.

Look into using a TransformationFilter http://docs.castleproject.org/MonoRail.Advanced-Topics.ashx#Transformation_Filters_14 which will allow you to manipulate the stream of data before it is sent to the client.

Comment: That's too bad.  Makes the templates rather unreadable.  I will eventually look for another template library since I don't really want to have to manipulate the datastream.

Comment: ok.  If you change your mind you can use see TransformFilter examples at https://github.com/castleproject/MonoRail/tree/master/MR2/src/Castle.MonoRail.Framework/TransformFilters